# Запрет автоматического решения конфликтов

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Пусть есть 3 ветки:

- master
- MR-1
- MR-2

1. Из ветки MR-1 открывается мёрдж-реквест в ветку master. Изменение в файле x.yaml на строке 1. Мердж-реквест висит
2. Из ветки MR-2 открывается мёрдж-реквест в ветку master. Изменение в файле x.yaml на строке 2. Мердж-реквест вмёрдживаем
3. Открываем MR-1 и видим, что он не имеет конфликтов. Хотя, в мастере есть изменения на строке 2, которых нет в ветке MR-1.

Почему в данном случае не происходит конфликтов и как их вызвать?

Данный кейс рассматривается в рамках гитлаба и он очень важен, когда 2 разработчика внесли изменения версий контейнеров в docker-compose.yml. При это последнему из них крайне важно знать, что в мастере произошли изменения.

Comment: А откуда бы возникли конфликты? Изменены разные строки, гит сам это разрулит. Вот если в обоих ветках изменить первую строку файла тогда да, будет конфликт

Comment: @Василиса как решить задачу? Мне, собственно, не очень интересно, почему так происходит. Намного важнее как решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

У `git merge` есть опция `--ff-only`, она не позволит вмержить ветку в мастер (например), если ветка не начата напрямую от текущего мастера.

Гитлаб [поддерживает](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/fast_forward_merge.html) эту настройку, в вашем случае он не позволит смержить MR-1 и предложит сделать ребейз. Ребейз пройдёт автоматически без конфликтов, но это хотя бы даст разработчику понимание того, что код в мастере был обновлен и надо бы посмотреть последние коммиты

Comment: Кажется, странным. Разраб просто нажмёт две кнопки. Кто читает, что написано на зелёной кнопке и рядом с ней?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, это единственное, что можно в данном случае сделать. Ситуация, которую вы описали в вопросе - довольно сложная проблема любой системы контроля версий. И автоматически она не решается.

Comment: Какие решения существуют? Веб-хуки. Может, у кого какие-то скрипты есть?